# How to create a loop for (or function) based on the column in R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I hve this data frame `df(A)`

```
col1  col2 col3 col4  col5
2      5    6    3.2   7
3      4    5    6     9
NA     NA   11   10    12
NA     NA   NA   NA    4.5
```

I would like this kind of operation, based on the column,an example:

```
A[,col1:col2]*5
A[,co3:col4]*6
A[,col5]*7
```

I need to create this with a loop `for`, i tried with:

```
result<- matrix(ncol=5,nrow=4)

for (i in dim(A)[1]{
 for (j in dim(A)[2]{
   if(j >=1 & j <=2){
      result[i,j] <- A*5}
   if(j>2 & j <=4){
      result[i,j] <- A*6}
   if (j>4){
      result[i,j] <- A*7}

 }
}
```

but R tell me:

```
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

The expected result is the matrix `result`,  with the value of `df(A)` multiplied for the correspondent value, based on the number of the column.
This example is simplify, my realy `df(A)` is biggest and the operation is more complicated. Is possible also using `function(A)`?

Comment: A* 5, A * 6, A * 7 produce matrices of dimension A. You are assigning it to a single element in the result matrix. Perhaps, it will help us help you if you provide sample input (in a format we can readily use) and also expected output.

Answer (score 3):

Work with a matrix and make use of vector recycling (we need to transpose twice because a matrix is filled column-wise).

```
DF <- read.table(text = "col1  col2 col3 col4  col5
2      5    6    3.2   7
3      4    5    6     9
NA     NA   11   10    12
NA     NA   NA   NA    4.5", header = TRUE)

t(t(as.matrix(DF)) * c(5, 5, 6, 6, 7))
#     col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
#[1,]   10   25   36 19.2 49.0
#[2,]   15   20   30 36.0 63.0
#[3,]   NA   NA   66 60.0 84.0
#[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA 31.5
```

Comment: Another possibility: `as.matrix(df)*rep(c(5,5,6,6,7),each=nrow(df))`

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
DF*c(5,5,6,6,7)[col(DF)]
#   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
#1   10   25   36 19.2 49.0
#2   15   20   30 36.0 63.0
#3   NA   NA   66 60.0 84.0
#4   NA   NA   NA   NA 31.5
```

---

Or with `sweep`

```
sweep(DF, 2, FUN="*", c(5, 5, 6, 6,7))
```